# Append data to existing gridfs file

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs, mongodb-java

As i can see java mongo driver does not provide capability to get `OutputStream` from existing gridFS file `com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSFile`

I have to create `GridFSInputFile` directly or use `gridFs.createFile()` method.

Is it a lack of java driver or a restriction of gridfs ?

Could you suggest any workaround except create new file/delete old one ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GridFS is not a core feature of MongoDB but a convention of storing binary data with accompanying metadata. You should be able to modify any document in `fs.chunks` collection in a usual manner while keeping corresponding document in `fs.files` intact. The main problem will be recalculating MD5 checksum, but AFAIK it isn't used anywhere and is just a "free" bonus. Anyway it's still possible for appending-only modification (see [MD5 digest of a resumed download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923362/md5-digest-of-a-resumed-download)).

So to append to an existing GridFS file you need to locate corresponding document in `fs.files`. Then depending on last chunk filling ratio (`length` % `chunkSize` == 0) you either rewrite the last chunk document in `fs.chunks` respecting the `chunkSize`, and/or simply add new chunk(s) with incrementing `n` field. Next update `length` in `fs.files` and possibly other metadata.

Comment: Yes, sound pretty easy, but i don't understand why they did not implement this feature themselves. Probably there are some pitfalls or other restrictions

Comment: ... I prefer to just save everything on a local file and once that is done upload the finished file to GridFS. It works well in the case where the files needs to be appended to initially but not modified later (e.g. you need to save a big file and you have constraints on request/chunk size). IMHO I'm astonished that very few drivers implement an append functionality... the fact that it is "easy" should be an extra reason for this to be included in all drivers, since it shouldn't be hard to include and maintain...