# Read subset of pickled NumPy array from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy

I have some NumPy arrays that are are pickled and stored in MongoDB using the `bson` module. For instance, if `x` is a NumPy array, then I set a field of a MongoDB record to:

```
bson.binary.Binary(x.dumps())
```

My question is whether it is possible to recover a subset of the array `x` without reloading the entire array via `np.loads()`. So, first, how can I get MongoDB to only give me back a chunk of the binary array, and then second, how can I turn that chunk into a NumPy array. I should mention here that I also have all the NumPy metadata regarding the array already, such as it's dimensions and datatype.

A concrete example might be that I have a 2-dimensional array of size (100000,10) with datatype `np.float64` and I want to retrieve just `x[50,10]`.

Comment: This is an interesting question, however, I believe that neither bson nor numpy data types can be 'abused' for this type of processing. However, maybe it's worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069905/how-to-efficiently-store-and-update-binary-data-in-mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I can not say for sure, but checking [the api docs](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_element.html#a8f4902eacf15f5069f4bb752bfd0aef4) of BSON C++ I get the idea that it was not designed for partial retrieval...

If you can at all, consider using [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin), which is designed for large data and inter-operating nicely with numpy. Mongo is great for certain distributed applications, though, while pytables is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the array directly inside of MongoDB, you can also try using the `$slice` operator to get a contiguous subset of an array.  You could linearize your 2D array into an 1D array, and the `$slice` operator will get you matrix rows, but if you want to select columns or generally select noncontiguous indicies, then you're out of luck.

Background on [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/).