# Spring Data MongoDB - Append binary data to existing GridFS file

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, gridfs

I'm implementing [TUS protocol](https://tus.io/) to upload large files using GridFS as persistence layer for the binary data. The idea is that the server will receive the data in chunks and append every new chunk into an existing resource. All the chunks will have the same size except for the last one.

I found [this workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280186/append-data-to-existing-gridfs-file) showing the idea of how to implement it myself but Im wondering if there is a way to append new chunks of binary data to an existing file using GridFSTemplate or other abstraction present on Spring Data Mongo project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridFS is a MongoDB-specific implementation. It could make sense to have appendable chunks in MongoDB's GridFS, the folks over at [MongoDB](https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/JAVA/issues) are the right people to talk to in the first place.

Spring Data MongoDB can only [implement such a functionality](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1861) if the driver provides it.

Although it' possible to work with MongoDB's file chunks directly, this would include implementation details in Spring Data MongoDB and bind the library to a particular implementation of GridFS. Spring Data isn't maintained by MongoDB but rather by the Spring Team which isn't involved in any change process happening within the scope of MongoDB. So if GridFS undergoes any changes in the future, this could break Spring Data MongoDB's support for appendable chunks.

Comment: I see what you mean.
The C# driver already exposes a method to do that so I'm hoping they will be able to implement it quite easily.
Here is the ticket for reference: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2765